# How to manually end a session in Google analytics v4 for Android?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I've been searching online for a few days but I couldn't find it. It was [available in v3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/sessions) but the only code available for managing the session manually in v4 is for [starting a new one](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/sessions) only and rely on the session timeout for the ending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The public Android v4 api doesn't have support for ending the session but you can accomplish the same with [session control end parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#sc) from Measurement Protocol. You can do that by adding sc=end to your Tracker:

```
analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

// TODO: Remove this line before shipping
analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);

tracker = analytics.newTracker(TRACKER_ID);
Map<String, String> hit = new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build();
hit.put("&sc", "end");
tracker.send(hit);
```

Verify that the sc parameter is send out by look at your logcat for "Sending hit" line and make sure it has sc=end parameter. It should look something like this:

```
V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to store  PATH: https:  PARAMS: v=1,  ul=en-us,  t=screenview,  ht=1417708068636,  sr=800x1216,  a=1647515955,  an=Analytics Playground,  sc=end,  tid=UA-xxxxxxxx-1,  aid=com.example.analyticsplayground,  cid=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx,  av=1.0,  _u=.nK-AL,
```

Comment: is this proven to work?

if i send sc=start (together with a pageview) i can see the hit in the realtime overview of my online ga console, and also the active users nbr turns from 0 to 1 (test profile of course);

when sending sc=end (again with another pageview), i also see this particular hit in the timeline, but the active users nbr only drops to zero after the usual timeout...

Comment: I believe active users is counted only over some period of time, not the actual exact active users. This is due to the fact that when user is not active anymore the app might not have a chance to let the server know its not active (for example when the device crashes or looses connectivity).